# Using Firebase-util to resolve one to many relationship

Tags: firebase

I've been looking at the firebase util project at https://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/.  I can't figure out if this is possible.

Say I have a data set like this:

```
{ clients:
   { client1: { groups: { group1: true, group2: true }, name: 'client1' },
     client2: { groups: { group3: true, group4: true }, name: 'client2' } },
  groups:
   { group1: { name: 'group1' },
     group2: { name: 'group2' },
     group3: { name: 'group3' },
     group4: { name: 'group4' },
     group5: { name: 'group5' } } }
```

I want to retrieve "client1" and resolve all the groups associated with client1, giving me back a dataset like this.

```
{ client1: { groups: { group1: { name: 'group1' }, group2: { name: 'group2' } }, name: 'client1' }
```

Is there a way to do this with Firebase-util?

There is an example on the website that is similar, where it is joining an account to a profile and then mapping the style to another reference point.

```
var ref = Firebase.util.join(
    new Firebase('INSTANCE/account'),
    {
       ref: new Firebase('INSTANCE/profile'),
       keyMap: {
          name: 'name',
          nick: 'nick',
          style: new Firebase('INSTANCE/styles')
       }
    }
);
```

But, I'm not seeing how to do it with what I'm looking for.

Something like:

```
FirebaseUtil.join(
  { ref: new Firebase('INSTANCE/clients/client1'), keyMap: {name: 'name', groups: new Firebase('INSTANCE/groups')} }
)
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: For that particular example I don't see a reason for using anything else but standard Firebase library.

Comment: @dusty your example looks fine, have you tried it? It's unclear what you're asking for help with.

Comment: Thanks @kato.  I'm getting an error that says "Cannot use child() to retrieve a dynamic keyMap ref; try loadChild() instead".  Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/affed5d60c27705cf479

Comment: This isn't possible in the current iteration. I'll be releasing some great updates to Firebase.util in the near future and I may be able to solve this case--I'll certainly keep it in mind. I've added a solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a nested list of groups as the keymap for `clients/$client/groups`. It must be a string pointing to exactly one reference.

The solution would be to retrieve the list separately from the meta data for the user:

```
var fb = new Firebase(URL);

getClients(fb.child('clients'), function(userId, data) {
   console.log(userId, data);
});

function getGroupsForClient(clientId, callback) {
   var indexRef = fb.child('clients/'+clientId+'/groups');
   var groupsRef = fb.child('groups');
   var intersectionRef = new Firebase.util.intersection(indexRef, groupsRef);
   intersectionRef.once('value', callback);
}

function getClients(callback) {
   fb.child('clients').on('child_added', function(snap) {
      var userId = snap.name();
      var userData = snap.val();
      getGroupsForClient(userId, function(snap) {
         userData.groups = snap.val();
         callback(userId, userData);
      });
   });
}
```